# How can I determine and enable/disable 2g or 3g programmatically with system privilegies?

Tags: android

How can I determine and enable/disable 2g or 3g programmatically? Assume I have an application with signed with system key. I want to learn the way how I can disable or enable the 3g.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535101/how-can-i-turn-off-3g-data-programmatically-on-android

Comment: @dutt not turn off/on, disable/enable