# Turn on/off mobile data in Android - NO REFLECTION

Tags: android, 3g

Is there a way to turn on/off, programmatically, mobile data in Android NOT USING REFLECTION? Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: also no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not supply an API method for disabling mobile data. So reflection is needed to achieve this.
[Here is a Stack Overflow thread that explains better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535101/how-can-i-turn-off-3g-data-programmatically-on-android)