# Switching mobile network programmatically

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to switch between mobile networks (UMTS -> GSM,...) by code?
When possible without rooting the device.
Thank you!

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535101/how-can-i-turn-off-3g-data-programmatically-on-android

Comment: This guy wants to enable and disable it. He does not want to change the network type.

Comment: Well disabling the UMTS Network would force your phone to switch onto GSM wouldn't it?

Comment: Ok and what if I want to switch from GSM to LTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not switch between 2G, 3G or 4G, as there is no api available in the android telephony manager which allows you to do so.

If there is different wifi network available then you can switch between those.

I hope, I have answered your question.

Thanks,